Azure Bicep - Load JSON printing content to Output
I am using BICEP to load configurations for creating resources (lets say redis caache)
like this
sample.json as follows
{ 
  "list":[    
    {
      "name":"rc1",
      "sku":"Standard",
      "family":"C",
      "capacity":1
    },
    {
      "name":"rc2",
      "sku":"Standard",
      "family":"C",
      "capacity":1
    }
  ]
}  

and then code to create resource (redis cache)
I am able to create Redis Cache but in the output entire json is getting printing
Could not find any solution to avoid json content from being printed to output console.

do you mind adding a resource block, so the situation is better understood.
